# Vertical Single Page App libs/patterns?

Tags: javascript, web-development, user-experience

Lately I've noticed a trend amongst some website homepages to present information in a vertical fashion, forcing the user to scroll down to continue reading the content. As you scroll down, a state transition occurs that has the *feeling* of an AJAX request and a new page/frame is presented to you with new content. I call this pattern the "vertical single page app (SPA)" for lack of a better term, and the best example of it that I've seen of this so far is [Google Deepmind](http://deepmind.com).

I looked at the page source for Deepmind but couldn't find any JS libs or dead giveaways as to what lib or pattern is being applied here.

Any ideas what this style/pattern is called, and what JS libs can be used to achieve it for a homepage or informational page?

Comment: I assume you're referring to the "smooth scrolling" that occurs on the Deepmind page, since there's nothing really interesting happening there otherwise.  Those page down buttons are effectively just anchor links, if you have the smooth scrolling in place.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/19349245.  You might also be interested in Parallax Scrolling.  By the way, the Javascript that drives the Deepmind website is at http://deepmind.com/scripts/app.js.  Yummy.

Comment: Bootstrap has a similar feature they call [ScrollSpy](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy). [Here's a nice writeup on SitePoint.com](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-bootstraps-affix-scrollspy-plugins/).